# Combine two validation controls as one

Tags: asp.net, validation, active-directory

I have two validation controls, can  I combine them into one?
The following is my original two controls, but it only works for first one. I realized that it might only have one validation control.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$"
                                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error, please reselect it" ControlToValidate="UserName">
                                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                <asp:CustomValidator
                                    ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Please select another name." ControlToValidate="UserName" OnServerValidate="ValidateUser"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And the validation in code behind:

```
 protected void ValidateUser(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        // check if the username created exists in AD already. 
        TextBox UserNameTextBox =
        (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
        string UserNameCreated = UserNameTextBox.Text;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cfs");
        entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + UserNameCreated + "))";

        SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
        Match match = Regex.Match(args.Value, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (results.Count > 0)
            args.IsValid = false;
        else if (match.Success)
            args.IsValid = true;
        else
            args.IsValid = false;
    }
```

Thanks.
Edit: the app can't reach here even I set a breakpoint.I removed the first validation control and only keep the second one.

Comment: Love have no control but can combine anything to one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Have the custom validator doing all the work of itself as above and also the regular expression validator. This is just one way if you want to do all your work as one item:

**ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />                            
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="UserName" OnServerValidate="ValidateUser"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**ASPX.CS Code: (code behind)**

```
protected void ValidateUser(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            Regex regx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$");
            if (regx.IsMatch(UserName.Text) == false)
            {
                CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Error, please reselect it";
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // check if the username created exists in AD already.
                TextBox UserNameTextBox =
                (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
                string UserNameCreated = UserNameTextBox.Text;
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cfs");
                entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

                DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + UserNameCreated + "))";

                SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
                if (results.Count > 0)
                {
                    CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Please select another name.";
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is some thing quick I could think of. Let me know how you go and what you think.

Comment: Great code. Another question, the CustomValidator is never fired.

Comment: Can you post your new code. Cause I have tested the above and it is.